# Demonstrate that p ↔ (p ↔ q) ⇔ q

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I know the answer is :

```
(p ↔ p) ↔ q ⇔ q
1 ↔ q ⇔ q
q ⇔ q
```

But I don't understand why it isn't :

```
(p ↔ p) ↔ q ⇔ q
1 ↔ q ⇔ q
(1 → q) ^ (q → 1) ⇔ q
(1 → q) ^ 1 ⇔ q
1 ⇔ q // fail !
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here: `(1 → q) ^ 1` should become `(1 → q)`, not `1`.  So, we'd be left with

```
       (1 → q) ⇔ q
```

Which leads us to the desired conclusion, `q ⇔ q`.

Comment: Sorry, I've been noob here. I mixed up AND and OR in my logic. Makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: No need to apologize.  Glad to help.